# Stata: using egen group() to create unique identifiers

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have a dataset where each row is a **firm, year** pair with a `firmid` that is a string.

If I do

```
duplicates drop firmid year, force
```

it doesn't delete anything since there are no duplicates (I originally created the dataset after running `duplicates drop firmid year, force`).

So far so good.  I want to create a panel which requires a `firmid` that is numeric.  So I run

```
egen newid = group(firmid)
xtset newid year
```

But the 'repeated time values in panel' error pops up.  Moreover,

```
duplicates list newid year
```

lists a whole bunch of duplicates.

It seems as though `egen, group()` isn't generating unique groups.  My question is: why, and how do I create unique groups in a robust way?

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example? For example, the complete offending code with a minimal data input that recreates the problem. See `help input` for creating short example data within a do-file.

Comment: Can you show the `firmid` for the duplicates? It would be handy to see all three variables when there are duplicates.

Comment: Yet another approach to consider is `encode`, see [help](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?encode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old thread, but I have recently experienced the same symptoms, so I wanted to share my solution. Of course, so long as the questioner does not give further details, we will not know whether the causes are the same for me and him.

The problem turned out to be an issue of precision. As explained [here](http://blog.stata.com/2012/04/02/the-penultimate-guide-to-precision/) in section 4.4, calculations done on integers stored as floats are precise only in the range up to 16,777,216. So, if you have more than 16,777,216 firms in your sample, rounding error will result in the same ID being assigned to multiple firms. This is straightforwardly dealt with by increasing the precision of the ID variable to long:

```
egen long newid = group(firmid)
```

Comment: You have put your finger on the likely problem, but `long` is usually a better alternative for integers that may be very large, as `long`s take up 4 bytes not 8 and can take values of more than 2 billion.

Comment: This was almost definitely the problem.  I was working with the US Census Bureau's confidential data and the list was huge.